# Strange tree traversing behavior in LibXml2 using C

Tags: c, xml, tree, libxml2

I have an XML file with devices in it structured as such:

```
<Device>
   <ID></ID>
   <VAL1></VAL1>
   <VAL2></VAL2>
   <VAL3></VAL3>
   <VAL4></VAL4>
   <VAL5></VAL5>
   <VAL6></VAL6>
</Device>
```

My function is meant to find the first `<Device>` element, and loop through the children elements of the Device and assure that no unexpected tags exist.

> NOTE: This function opens the XML file using the XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS
>   option, and curNode is only examined if it is an XML_ELEMENT_NODE

```
// If current node is opening Device tag for a device
if (xmlStrcmp(curNode->name, (const xmlChar*)"Device") == 0)
{
   // Loop through child nodes and assure that they match
   // a valid tag and have no other children tag elements
   childNode = curNode->children;

   while (childNode != NULL)
   {
      if (childNode->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE)
      {
         for (nIdx = 0; nIdx < 7; nIdx++)
         {
            if (xmlStrcmp(childNode->name, 
                         (const xmlChar*)acXmlChildTags[nIdx]) == 0)
            {
               bChildFound = TRUE;
               break;
            }
         }
         if (bChildFound != TRUE)
         {
            nReturnValue = FAILURE;
            break;
         }
      }
      childNode = xmlNextElementSibling(childNode);
   }
}
```

`acXmlChildTags` is an array of `char*` equal to the tag strings ("ID", "VAL1" etc)

Aside from any issues in the overall logic here, because parts of the function are excluded, what I'm noticing is my function correctly reaches the "VAL6" element inside of the "Device", but when I go to the next element it jumps back up "VAL3", then continues back down to "VAL6" and then finally reaches the NULL next element to break out of the loop.

Can anyone explain to me why going to the next element sibling of the last child element of "Device" is pushing me back into the 3rd child element?

I apologize in advance for the convoluted question.

Comment: why not just use `childNode = childNode->next;`?

Comment: have you checked the `else`-part to `if (type)`? maybe you run a path you did not expect.

Comment: @PeterMiehle I started out using `childNode->next` and that showed the same results. The `else` condition is actually never hit, its there "just in case"

Comment: @PeterMiehle It basically acts like my child tree under `Device` looks like this: `ID->VAL1->VAL2->VAL3->VAL4->VAL5->VAL6->VAL3->VAL4->VAL5->VAL6->NULL`

Comment: Perhaps I just need to rethink this and use XPath to check for a tag within the `Device` element rather than loop through

Comment: This should work. I would either use `childNode = childNode->next` *or* keep `xmlNextElementSibling()` but use `xmlFirstElementChild()` to get the first child (in which case you can dispense with checking the node type). Can you post a simple self-contained example (compilable) which illustrates the problem?

Comment: I found the issue. I screwed up my XML files and was trying to parse a test file that I added extra entries into. Yikes. Apologies.